# Reshaping large data set

Tags: r, reshape2

I am trying to reformat my data set. Currently, this is what it looks like:

| SeqId | PlateId | Target | TargetFullName |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 11 | 111 | 111 |
| 2 | 22. | 222. | 2222. |

However, I'd like it to look like this:

| ----- | SeqId | PlateId | TargetFullName |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Target | - | - | - |
| 111 | 1 | 11 |  | 111 |
| 222 | 2 | 22 | 222 |

This is what I have for reshaping:

```
library(reshape2)
longnewData <- melt(newData)
(differentSeqs <- getSequencesWithLargestBetweenGroupVariation(
  longnewData, n=10))[,.(SeqId, Target)]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated -- thanks!

Comment: It looks like you want to assign a column as rownames. Is that correct? If it is, you can achieve this by simply setting `row.names(df) <- df$Target; df$Target <- NULL`.

Comment: Having said that, rownames have grown out of fashion in the `R` world. Some data structures like `tibbles` or `data.tables` may not work as well with them.

Comment: Essentially, my columns are named SeqId, PlateId, Target, Intensity, etc. However, I would like to create a data frame with the Target Names as the rows and include Intensity and SeqId as columns. How can I drop these additional columns and change the rows to Target names?

Comment: Does the initial code not do that that I posted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to achieve what you want:

###### Data:

```
df <- data.frame(SeqId = 1:2, 
                 PlateId = c(11,22), 
                 Target = c(111,222), 
                 TargetFullName = c(111, 2222))
```

###### Turning column into row:

```
row.names(df) <- df$Target; df$Target <- NULL
```

###### Checking outcome:

```
df
    SeqId PlateId TargetFullName
111     1      11            111
222     2      22           2222
```

Comment: @skabir if this worked, please feel free to accept the answer by clicking on the v sign next to the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

We could also use this:

```
library(tibble)

df %>% column_to_rownames("Target")

    SeqId PlateId TargetFullName
111     1      11            111
222     2      22           2222
```